# Wordpress Admin-ajax.php file stuck in File manager

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, hosting, cpanel

One of my WordPress sites was causing a problem with updating plugin and theme. Anyway, I uninstalled the WordPress from Cpanel and found **admin-ajax.php**(file permission was 0000) could be deleted. I have tried to change the permission of the file from Cpanel and also from ftp, but neither had worked.
[you can see the permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0k8l.png)
Then I removed the domain from hosting but that is also nor working. Cpanel error log is also showing nothing.
[this is from ftp trying to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDksj.png)
 I need to delete that folder, any solutions would be a great help.

Comment: il file permission is set with 0000 i suggest you to ask to your hosting provider service help to delete that file, you should'nt be able to edit/delete it from ftp

Comment: thanks for answering, they removed the file.